# How to cite a Newspaper Article in Latex using Chicago Manual of Style

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style, online

I need to get something like this:

> Jaggi, Maya. “Interview with Amy Tan.” The Guardian. Guardian News and Media, March 3, 2001. https://www.theguardian.com/books/2001/mar/03/fiction.features.

Using the code:

```
@Electronic{jaggi_2001, 
title={Interview with Amy Tan}, 
url= {theguardian.com/books/2001/mar/03/fiction.features}, 
journal={The Guardian}, 
publisher={Guardian News and Media}, 
author={Jaggi, Maya}, 
year={2001}, 
month={Mar}}
```

In Latex, using Chicago Manual Style. The main problem I am facing is to use which one of the `@Book`, `@Article`, `@Misc`, `@Online` etc. I have tried all of them but could not get the above result.

The source for the above style is at https://libguides.williams.edu/citing/chicago-author-date#s-lg-box-12037256

Will appreciate if someone has used any technique for this.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide your code in question. link can be dead after while, so other will not able to see your problem.

Comment: I am using this command line for Bibliography generation: 
                                                                                        
 \bibliographystyle{chicago} and using \usepackage{mychicago}. and in the Bibtex file, I am using @Electronic{jaggi_2001, 
title={Interview with Amy Tan}, 
url= {https://www.theguardian.com/books/2001/mar/03/fiction.features}, 
journal={The Guardian}, 
publisher={Guardian News and Media}, 
author={Jaggi, Maya}, 
year={2001}, 
month={Mar}}

Comment: Are you willing to switch to `biblatex`? Customising `chicago.bst` is a pain, but newspaper articles are supported out of the box using `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: @David Purton, please guide me how to do that...yes, I may switch

Answer (score 4):

You can use `biblatex-chicago` instead of `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` and `\usepackage{mychicago}` (probably: I don't know what this is, but presumably it is a modified version of `chicago.sty`).

`biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` are highly and easily customisable and both have excellent documentation. There are also many questions on this site about using them.

A simple MWE for `biblatex-chicago` looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jaggi_2001,
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
  author = {Jaggi, Maya},
  date = {2001-03-03},
  title = {Interview with Amy Tan},
  journaltitle = {The Guardian},
  url = {https://www.theguardian.com/books/2001/mar/03/fiction.features}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{jaggi_2001}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can you please look into the code again, as I am copy pasting ur code but not getting the same result!

Comment: @HasanNoorKhan, You probably need to set up your editor to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: @HasanNoorKhan, See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154794/87678